# Пропала репутация рядом с ником

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, дизайн, репутация

Это так и задумано или багулина?

Теперь не потешить свое самолюбие=(

Comment: Причем пропала местами https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyvZR.png

Comment: Может коммунизм пришел на SO и теперь все равны, что бы не оскорблять меньшинства...

Comment: И правильно, давно пора удалить. Ведь это может привести к дискриминации или обидеть кого-то. На SO все равны. И Скит с 1Мrep и любой новичок с 1rep. Некрасиво выставлять напоказ чьи-то недостатки. Отличная инициатива для нового CoC // это был сарказм, если что

Comment: Толерантность к угнетаемым  ̶м̶е̶н̶ь̶ш̶и̶н̶с̶т̶в̶а̶м̶  большинствам добралась и до SO.

Comment: ветка на мете посвященная этому же багу https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390269/is-so-running-another-experiment-by-hiding-the-user-information-or-is-it-a-bug (а я, все таки, надеюсь что это баг)

Comment: @Andrew, это вы просто в чат не заходите и всех новостей не знаете :) И да, это уже не шутка, к сожалению

Comment: А если навести курсор на портрет, то репа отображается. Такое раньше было? Не замечал...

Comment: @iluxa1810 да, было. Начиная с некоей репутации. Поищи в справке с какой репутации появляется расширенная информация при наведении курсора.

Comment: [This is a bug, a fix is incoming. – Taryn♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390269/is-so-running-another-experiment-by-hiding-the-user-information-or-is-it-a-bug#comment733693_390269)

Comment: @iluxa1810, это фича 1к https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

Comment: @АндрейNOP не думаю что это решит проблему. Ведь, не хотят помогать новичкам не потому что "новички", а потому, что зачастую они получают ответ и вопрос не отмечают как решенный. Да и сама формулировка вопроса выдает новичка на раз.... Уверен, что скрывание кармы ничегошеньки не даст, если это фича. А то и может привести к противоположному эфекту)

Comment: Ну вот и все. Пофиксили багу) Вопрос можно закрывать

Answer (score 8):

Баг - не баг : в выдаче сервера все есть, убрано стилем  на фронтэнде

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]